# Example of a gridview bound to a collection in Pyramid?

Tags: python, gridview, pyramid

I have a service leveraging a REST API using a `BackgroundScheduler` triggering jobs based on a given interval. I would like that every time the function associated with the job is triggered, it refreshes automatically a gridview with a collection that has been previously updated by the job.

It does not seem that there is in Pyramid or any other framework, a gridview component that would support collection changes on which the component would be bound to.

Is there a simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to async refresh gridview in browser check websockets (example https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)